# can we have multiple BTC addresses that all of them store their values in the same place?

Tags: wallet, address-generation, payment

I am creating my own shop and I will give each user an address to specify who is sending me BTC but when I want to collect all BTC address values to my main address I need to pay fees a lot since each subaddress has a little value on it.

is there a way to create a sum address refer to one address or any way to store automatically in one place/address? thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are accepting small payments and are rightfully worried about fees, you might want to look into Lightning Network.

Comment: Also, collecting all received BTC to a "main address" is address reuse, which should be avoided: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address_reuse

Answer (score 2):

This should be in the comments but my initial reputation does not allow for that.

You seem to be from Turkey. IIRC the 3rd party payment processing got banned in your country this year.

This leaves you with self-hosted payment processors like BTCPay Server or CypherpunkPay.

Regarding your question, as others pointed out, it's not possible to "add" to existing UTXO. You can only combine multiple UTXO-s by periodically transferring back to yourself which is smart long-term-fee-wise but bad privacy-wise.

Realistically, disallow small on-chain payments and/or implement accepting Lightning Network payments.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do what you suggest using on-chain transactions.

The lightning network or a payment service might help achieve your goals.